# Has Connect Four been solved on arbitrary board sizes?

Tags: algorithm

Victor Allis in his program VICTOR used his algorithm for six by seven connect four, his algorithm has proven to give a sure win.

Is it possible to have similar algorithm for x by y board?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's no formula to determine which player wins (or whether it's a forced draw) on an $x$ by $y$ board, other than just letting a dedicated (complicated) solver program run a few hours/weeks/years.

On a 7 by 6 board, the first player wins, but for example on an 8 by 8 board, it's a win for the second player, as mentioned [here](https://www.littlegolem.net/jsp/forum/topic2.jsp?forum=80&topic=77), linking to [this GitHub page](https://github.com/tromp/fhourstones88).